# Enumeration in iphone is not working

Tags: iphone, enums

i am developing an iphone application in which i have 3 classes => main class , abc class, pqr class. On main view , i have imageview on which i am displaying image. when user touch at the center of image on main view , new view will be pushed (depending on condition mentioned below)

a)  if user came from **abc view** then 
**new view will not be pushed**

b) if user came from **pqr view** then i 
**have to push new view** .

My problem is how can i detect from which view user came to main view.

I create 1 class in which i have following code in .h file

```
typedef enum {
        abcViewSelected,
        pqrViewSelected
} SelectedViewType;

@interface Enumeration : NSObject {
    SelectedViewType selectedViewType;
}

@property(nonatomic) SelectedViewType selectedViewType;
```

In . m file i have

```
@synthesize selectedViewType;
```

When user select table cell from abcView & pqrView , i am pushing main view & setting view type in didSelectRowAtIndexPath as follows :-

```
enumObj.selectedViewType = abcViewSelected;

enumObj.selectedViewType = pqrViewSelected;
```

In main view's touchBegan method i am compairing which view is selected by writing this

```
if(enum.selectedViewType == pqrViewSelected) => push new view
```

else do nothing.

But this is not compairing & in none of case new view is pushed.  I have imported all the required header files everywhere.

Plz help me ....Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the if you typed in the question is correct, you are using `=` instead of `==` to compare (plus, it should read `enumObj.selectedViewType`)

Comment: sorry friends , its " == " instead of " = ". it was my typing mistake in question. Still its not working. If u have any other solution , most welcome. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem must be in this line:

```
if(enum.selectedViewType = pqrViewSelected)
```

Here you do not compare current type value, but rather assign pqrViewSelected to it (you have '=' instead of '=='). Try changing that line to:

```
if(pqrViewSelected == enum.selectedViewType){
    // push view
}
```

Note that having constant expression as first parameter in comparison makes it impossible to mistakingly use assignment ('=') instead of comparison ('==').

Comment: @ Vladimir : If i use ur code (pqrViewSelected == enum.selectedViewType) then new view is not pushed in any case.
I used "==" . Plz help me friends. thanks in advance

Comment: what is 'enum' in your case? and have you tried to debug your program to see actual values to find what could possibly went wrong with them...

Comment: I tried to debug. I put 2 NSLog statements like this     NSLog(@"Before if loop");                                if(enum.selectedView == pqrVIewSelected) {//pushview};                   NSLog(@"After if loop");                              When i run in console i get  "after if loop" printed. Its not executing if loop.